# How can I switch on Intellisense and code hints in C++ Builder 2009?

Tags: intellisense, c++builder

I've just installed CodeGear Studio 2009 and I didn`t find where I can put the Intellisense and code hints on.

And, by the way, in Visual Studio we can indent selected blocks of code in the same way. How can I use similar functions in CodeGear?

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Code Insight. I don't have 2009 yet but it's probably in the same place as 2007. Have a look in **Tools > Options > Editor Options > Code Insight**.

By the way, it's no where near as good as Intellisense in VS.

Answer (score 0):

The generic name is called "code completing", intellisense and insight are just catching marketing spun names companies use.

Answer (score 0):

even after I`ve relaunched it with all points of CodeInsight turned on I found out that there was no result((